# Beanstalk: Error while updating environment with new version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy a Ruby-on-Rails application to AWS Beanstalk. The war is generated using warble in Jenkins and the war file is then copied to our AWS S3 bucket.

I am using AWS Beanstalk command-line tools to create the beanstalk application, application version and the environment. The first version is deployed correctly.

Then I create a new application version, and try updating environment with the new version. The new version is not getting deployed. In the events, following error is thrown:

```
Encountered errors while attempting to deploy version to 1 running EC2 instances
```

I have tried creating everything from the scratch as well, but still the 2nd version onward above error is thrown.

Note: We are using custom AMI, this is the BS AMI which we tweaked and created image from for our use.

Can someone help me with this, please?

Thanks

Noman A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering this on the basis of my testings, so anyone looking for solutions might find it useful.

As mentioned in the question, I was using a custom beanstalk ami [Tomcat 7 stack]. The customization was done following below steps:

1. Create Beanstalk Application, create a version for this app, and launch beanstalk environment (Not customized one, default as provided by AWS) by passing options like KeyPair so you can use the same to ssh into the instance.
2. Note the AMI-id of the above instance and launch a regular EC2 (Not Beanstalk) instance of this AMI.
3. Customzie the EC2 instance to your needs, and create an EBS Image of this instance once done. Stop this instance, you can terminate it later once you are happy with the image.
4. Terminate the Beanstalk instance as well.
5. Launch new Beanstalk environment, but this time pass this ami-id of the image created in step 3.

I have created customized beanstalk images for both tomcat 6 and 7. For my problem, I found out that the issue was happening when I was using a customized ami for tomcat 7. The update just didn't work. But when I use beanstalk default instance (not the customized image of mine), the update works fine.

However, with the tomcat 6 customized image, update works just fine. So it appears the issue is with the AWS Beanstalk Default AMI for Tomcat 7 customization.

I am marking this one as answered for now.

-Noman A.

Comment: I've got the same issue with PHP instances. Fallowed the same steps except for nr 2 where I tried with one of available instances PHPBeanstalk AMI's from AMAZON. I think problem was caused with 'yum update'. I'll try from scratch and share what'll happen

Comment: Sure, let us know what happens, and see if folks here can help with it.

Comment: I actually did the same steps, but instead of doing full 'yum update' I only updated PHP. That worked!!! This is suggesting that updating whole system breaks some dependencies required for Beanstalk's hostmanager. Hope this helps to somebody

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for sharing your experience and solution!

Comment: I am having a similar problem when running "yum update" on a custom AMI. After running the update the AMI does not work with EBS anymore.